# strip data from a text file

Tags: java, regex, fileinputstream, datainputstream

Im going to start by posting what the date in the text file looks like, this is just 4 lines of it, the actually file is a couple hundred lines long.

Friday, September  9 2011
-STV 101--------05:00 - 23:59     SSB 4185              Report Printed on 9/08/2011 at  2:37

0-AH  104--------07:00 - 23:00     AH GYM               Report Printed on 9/08/2011 at  2:37

-BG  105--------07:00 - 23:00     SH GREAT HALL         Report Printed on 9/08/2011 at  2:37

What I want to do with this text file is ignore the first line with the date on it, and then ignore the '-' on the next line but read in the "STV 101", "5:00" and "23:59" save them to variables and then ignore all other characters on that line and then so on for each line after that.

Here is how I am currently reading the lines entirely. And then I just call this function once the user has put the path in the scheduleTxt JTextfield. It can read and print each line out fine.

```
public void readFile () throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(scheduleTxt.getText());
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;

        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
        {
            System.out.println (strLine);
        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

UPDATE: it turns out I also need to strip Friday out of the top line and put it in a variable as well
Thanks! Beef.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did not test it thoroughly, but this regular expression would capture the info you need in groups 2, 5 and 7: (Assuming you're only interested in "AH 104" in the example of "0-AH 104----")
        `^(\S)*-(([^-])*)(-)+((\S)+)\s-\s((\S)+)\s(.)*`

```
    String regex = "^(\\S)*-(([^-])*)(-)+((\\S)+)\\s-\\s((\\S)+)\\s(.)*";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strLine);
        boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
        if (matchFound){
            String s1 = matcher.group(2);
            String s2 = matcher.group(5);
            String s3 = matcher.group(7);
            System.out.println (s1 + " " + s2 + " " + s3);
        }

    }
```

The expression could be tuned with non-capturing groups in order to capture only the information you want.

Explanation of the regexp's elements:

1. `^(\S)*-` Matches group of non-whitespace characters ended by `-`. *Note*: Could have been `^(.)*-` instead, would not work if there are whitespaces before the first `-`.
2. `(([^-])*)` Matches group of every character except `-`.
3. `(-)+` Matches group of one or more `-`.
4. `((\S)+)` Matches group of one or more non-white-space characters. This is captured in group 5.
5. `\s-\s` Matches group of white-space followed by `-` followed by whitespace.
6. '((\S)+)' Same as 4. This is captured in group 7.
7. `\s(.)*` Matches white-space followed by anything, which will be skipped.

More info on regular expression can be found on this [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). 
There are also several useful [cheatsheets](http://www.omicentral.com/cheatsheets/JavaRegularExpressionsCheatSheet.pdf) around. When designing/debugging an expression, a [regexp testing tool](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm) can prove quite useful, too.

Comment: Yes in the case of "0-AH 104----" I only want the "AH 104", thanks, I'll give it a try and see what I get!

Comment: Update: Worked great, tested it with more extensive versions of the text file and worked without a problem, thanks again

Comment: I've added explanation of the elements on the expression on the answer for further reference

Comment: @Beef If the file format is fixed, you could just look for `,` in the string before testing the expression, and keep the `strLine.split(",")[0]`.

Comment: I was just informed that I may be working with a different format than this one, but I am going to argue against it, but if I do have to use a different format hopefully I can use your edit of the answer to help make changes to the regex search accordingly

Comment: @Beef I'll be happy if that edit helps you understanding regexps and tailoring it to your own needs :)

Comment: I dont know if you will be checking this but I had another regex related question Im trying to work through, here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7432018/strip-data-from-text-file-using-regex